# Ruby: why use # not /?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

In the following, what is the reason for having `#home` rather than `/home`? All others are `/help`, `/about`.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  'static_pages/help'
  get  'static_pages/about'
end
```

Comment: The above is part of the below tutorial: http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/static_pages?version=4.2#code-home_root_route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the full equivalent of the code you provided:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/',                  to: 'static_pages#home'
  get 'static_pages/help',  to: 'static_pages#help'
  get 'static_pages/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
end
```

The hash symbol `#` divides controller and action names in route destination string.

In your example you use the `root` method. It is a shorthand for `get '/'`. So you don't specify the request path.

In the last two rules, destination can be omitted because Rails calculates it automatically.

I suggest that you read the official [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). It explains all these things.

Comment: thank you!! but why not just write:  root 'static_pages/home'

Comment: I think this is because Rails will be confused: did you specify request path or controller+action string?

Comment: thank you!!! I got it with your above revised explanation!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You're welcome :) Could you accept this answer if you like it?